# Polynomial roots distance

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Does there exist a quadratic polynomial $x^2 + px + q$ with the property that $p$
and $q$ can be changed by no more than 0.01 so that at least one of the roots of the polynomial
changes by at least 100?

Work:
The roots are 
$$x_1=\frac{p_1\pm\sqrt{p_1^2-4q_1}}{2}$$
$$x_2=\frac{p_2\pm\sqrt{p_2^2-4q_2}}{2}$$
Since they are talking about the "leftmost" or"rightmost" roots, we prove
$$\bigg|\frac{p_2-p_1+\sqrt{p_2^2-4q_2}-\sqrt{p_1^2-4q_1}}{2}\bigg|<100$$
WLOG,
$$\frac{\sqrt{p_2^2-4q_2}-\sqrt{p_1^2-4q_1}}{2}<99.995$$
How can I prove this. The square roots are tricky to deal with.

I know I already posted it, but the other question is currently on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the distance between the two roots of $x^2+px+q$ is $\sqrt{p^2-4q}$ (provided the roots are real).

Consider $x^2-2ax+a^2$ and $x^2-(2a+.01)x+a^2$. The first has a double root at $a$, the latter has roots $x_1,x_2$ with
$$|x_1-x_2|=\sqrt{(2a+.01)^2-4a^2}=\sqrt{0.04a+0.0001}. $$
By making $a$ large enough, this becomes $>200$, hence at least one of the roots has moved by at least $100$ from the former double root $a$
Specifically, we can take $a=1000000$.